# insertion sort using the data from operation file

Tags: c, sorting, file-io, insertion-sort

I need to make a sorting program specifically insertion sort where the data came from the operation file that I already made before, but the data from the operation file can't be passed to the sorting program which is affected the output too. I really appreciate you guys who were willing to help me, thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main

 ()
{
    FILE *af = fopen("modul.txt", "r");
    int i, n, j, key;
    char id[6], eko[5], geo[5], sos[5], sej[5], pil;
    printf("DATA NILAI UTBK SOSHUM 2019\n");
    i=1;
    do{
        printf("\t\t  | id | eko | geo | sos | sej |\n");
        do{
            fscanf(af, "%s %s %s %s %s", id, eko, geo, sos, sej);
            printf("Data input ke-%d : |%s|-|%s|-|%s|-|%s|-|%s|\n", i, id, eko, geo, sos, sej);
            i++;
        }
        while(!feof(af));
        
        //mengurutkan data dengan metode INSERTION SHORT
        printf("\nMengurutkan nilai TKA Soshum UTBK 2019\n");
        printf("1. Nilai Ekonomi\n"); printf("2. Nilai Geografi\n"); printf("3. Nilai Sosiologi\n"); printf("4. Nilai Sejarah\n");
        printf("Masukkan Pilihan : "); fflush(stdin); scanf("%c", &pil);
        
        if (pil == '1')
        {
            printf("Nilai Ekonomi\n");
            FILE *af = fopen("modul.txt", "r");
            fscanf(af, "%s", eko[i]);
            for (i=1; 1<=eko[i]; i++)
            {
                key = eko[i];
                j = i-1;
                while (j>=0 && eko[j]>key)
                {
                    eko[j+1] = eko[j];
                    j = j-1;
                }
                    eko[j+1] = key;
            }
            
            for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                fscanf(af, "%s", eko[i]);
                printf("%s", eko[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        
        else if (pil == '2')
        {
            printf("2. Nilai Geografi\n");
            for (i=1; 1<=n; i++)
            {
                key = geo[i];
                j = i-1;
                while (j>=0 && geo[j]>key)
                {
                    geo[j+1] = geo[j];
                    j = j-1;
                }
                geo[j+1] = key;
            }
            
            for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                printf("%d", geo[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        
        else if (pil == '3')
        {
            printf("3. Nilai Sosiologi\n");
            for (i=1; 1<=n; i++)
            {
                key = sos[i];
                j = i-1;
                while (j>=0 && sos[j]>key)
                {
                    sos[j+1] = sos[j];
                    j = j-1;
                }
                sos[j+1] = key;
            }
            
            for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                printf("%d", sos[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        
        else if (pil == '4')
        {
            printf("4. Nilai Sejarah\n");
            for (i=1; 1<=n; i++)
            {
                key = sej[i];
                j = i-1;
                while (j>=0 && sej[j]>key)
                {
                    sej[j+1] = sej[j];
                    j = j-1;
                }
                sej[j+1] = key;
            }
            
            for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                printf("%d", sej[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        
        else 
        {
            printf("Salah Masukkan Pilihan\nUlangi Lagi!");
        }
    }
    while(!feof(af));
    fclose(af);

}
```

all I need was how I can pass the data from the operation file to the sorting program

Comment: The "operation file" is `modul.txt`?

Comment: Anyway, two programs exchange data via a file by one writing to the file and the other reading from it what was written.  The program in the question already appears to demonstrate opening and reading from a file, so it's unclear to me what else you want to know.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "but the data from the operation file can't be passed to the sorting program which is affected the output too". Please [edit] your question and show the input you use, the actual output/result/behavior or error you get and the expected output/result/behavior.